# add UIWebView to MKPinAnnotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift

Hey I have been looking around for this answer but can't seem to find any haha. So what I'm looking at is to add a UIWebView to MKPinAnnotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView so that I can use html to do some formatting. But it's not working properly. see my code below.

```
view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
view.canShowCallout = true
view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)

let detailView = UIWebView()
let poi = annotation as POI

var htmlString: String = "<html><body><p>"
htmlString = htmlString + "<b><font size = \"3\">" + poi.title! + "</font></b><br>"
htmlString = htmlString + "Number of Reviews: " + String(poi.review_count) + "<br>"
htmlString = htmlString + "</p></body></html>"

detailView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
view.detailCalloutAccessoryView = detailView
```

And the results I'm getting looks like this.

[image]

Only the title shows up, which I also believes come from MKAnnotation.title instead of my UIWebView. Did anyone encountered this problem before? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `UIWebView` to `detailCalloutAccessoryView`, but you are not setting the frame for you `UIWebView` instance. Try doing following.

```
let detailView = UIWebView()
detailView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)  //set your custom height and width
```

That should add `UIWebView` to `detailCalloutAccessoryView`.